# Why doesn't the learning rate (LR) go below 1e-08 in pytorch?

Tags: optimization, deep-learning, pytorch, gradient-descent

I am training a model. To overcome overfitting I have done optimization, data augmentation etc etc. I have an updated LR (I tried for both SGD and Adam), and when there is a plateu (also tried step), the learning rate is decreased by a factor until it reaches LR 1e-08 but won't go below than that and my model's validation gets stuck after this point. I tried passing the epsilon parameter to Adam to suggest a smaller value, but it still got stuck at LR 1e-08. I also pass a weight decay, but it doesn't change the situation. Neither did setting the amsgrad to true.

I did some research and people suggest that Adam optimizer has inherent problems but nothing is mentioned about the learning rate - and every discussion added that with SGD, there is no problem.

Why is this? Is it a bug or is it designed so because authors think it is meaninglessly a small value after that? It seems like it would really help to have a smaller learning rate for my dataset because all seems well up until learning rate is down to LR 1e-08.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Personally I'm not aware of a lower limit on the learning rate (other than 0.0). But you can achieve the effect of a lower learning rate by reducing the loss before computing the backwards pass:

```
outputs = model(batch)
loss = criterion(outputs, targets)

# Equivalent to lowering the learning rate by a factor of 100
loss = loss / 100

self.optimizer.zero_grad()
loss.backward()
self.optimizer.step()
```

Comment: can you please explain a bit more or give some intuition on why scaling the loss function also scales the learning rate? - Thankyou

Comment: because of the way gradient descent works ![w_{k+1}-\alpha\nabla L(w_{k})](https://latex.codecogs.com/gif.latex?w_%7Bk&plus;1%7D-%5Calpha%5Cnabla%20L%28w_%7Bk%7D%29) so any rescaling of the loss function can be equivalently absorbed into the learning rate.

Comment: Because the equation of gradient descent is w_{k+1}-\alpha\nabla L(w_{k}). Hence any scalar transformation of the loss can be equivalently absorbed into the learning rate. I.e. dividing the loss by 10 is the same as an unchanged loss and a lower learning rate.

Answer (score 4):

Richard's work around should work pretty well, but I have also gotten an official answer if anyone would care to know.

Setting a smaller value to ReduceLROnPlateau scheduler's (and not Adam's) eps parameter has worked.

eps ( float ) – Minimal decay applied to lr. If the difference between new and old lr is smaller than eps, the update is ignored. Default: 1e-8.

Answer (score 0):

The real question you should be asking yourself? Is why do I keep on needing to reduce the learning rate?

The highly simplified answer that you are looking for and striding towards with your continual learning rate drops (but not actually getting there) is that you are trying to reduce the relative noise to signal (i.e. the variance of your update).

Have you perhaps tried averaging out the gradient iterates and keeping your learning rate flat? something like this should do

https://www.tensorflow.org/addons/api_docs/python/tfa/optimizers/SWA